# weather Jquery wunderground get empty data

Tags: jquery

```
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
} else { 
  x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
}

function showPosition(position) {
  var location = position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude; 

  $(document).ready(function(load) {
    var dmJSON = "https://api.wunderground.com/api/0ce1c4a981f7dd2a/geolookup/lang:AR/forecast/conditions/q/"+location+".json";
    dataType : "jsonp";

    function fetch() {
      $.getJSON( dmJSON, function(parsed_json) {
        var html = '';
        {
          html += '<div style="width: 600;direction: rtl;background-color: white;padding: 12px 12px 0;border: 1px solid;border-color: #e5e6e9 #dfe0e4 #d0d1d5;border-radius: 4px;margin-bottom: 20px;color: black;">';

          html += '<p>' + parsed_json.current_observation.weather  + ' </p>';
          html += '</div>';
        }
        setInterval(function () {
          $(news).html(""); 
          fetch();
        }, 15000);
        fetch();
        $("#news").append(html);
     })
   }
 });
} // a
```

I don't think there have error , but i dont know why i get empty weather data wunderground , This is the first time I am using this wunderground.I want to get weather data , i get the geoloction but we have empty data

Comment: You are totally confusing the way of using the Script. Why can't you align it and make it readable?

Comment: am confused @PraveenKumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be a corrected "attempt" to solve your question, but not a complete answer. The geoLocation API is asynchronous, so you need to use in a different way. And you have had a lot of syntax errors. I am surprised how it didn't give you. You are not calling `fetch()`:

```
$(document).ready(function(load) {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else { 
    $("#demo").html("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
  }
  function showPosition(position) {
    var location = position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude;
    var dmJSON = "https://api.wunderground.com/api/0ce1c4a981f7dd2a/geolookup/lang:AR/forecast/conditions/q/"+location+".json";
    fetch(dmJSON);
  }
  function fetch(dmJSON) {
    $.getJSON( dmJSON, function(parsed_json) {

      var html = '';
      html += '<div style="width: 600;direction: rtl;background-color: white;padding: 12px 12px 0;border: 1px solid;border-color: #e5e6e9 #dfe0e4 #d0d1d5;border-radius: 4px;margin-bottom: 20px;color: black;">';
      html += '<p>' + parsed_json.current_observation.weather  + ' </p>' ;
      html += '</div>';
      setInterval(function () {
        $(news).html(""); 
        fetch(dmJSON);
      }, 15000);
      $("#news").append(html);
    });
  }
});
```